# Problem with installing dev tools packadge

Tags: r

So , I am following instructions given to us on how to install dev.tools package.
But, I am running into a problem where after being successful at using these commands:
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

I am instructed to use this command:
build_github_devtools()
Which produces this error :

Error in build_github_devtools() :
could not find function "build_github_devtools"

I have no idea how to solve this, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be following outdated instructions. According to the install guide at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/readme/README.html , you are good to go!

If you were successful with

```
install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools)
```

That's it, mission accomplished